# React event handlers with Typescript and JSX

Tags: typescript, reactjs

I'm having problems updating state in a React component I'm writing in TypeScript (React with Addons 0.13.3, Typescript 1.6.0-dev.20150804, definition file from http://definitelytyped.org/).

```
/// <reference path="react/react-addons.d.ts" />
import React = require("react/addons");

interface AppState {
}

interface TestState {
    liked: boolean,
    name: string
}

class Tester extends React.Component<any, TestState> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { liked: false, name: "Anders" };
    }

    handleClick(evt, domNode): void {
        this.setState({ liked: !this.state.liked, name: this.state.name });
    }

    handleChange(evt, a, b, c): void {
        this.setState({ liked: this.state.liked, name: evt.target.value });
    }

    render() {
        var text = this.state.liked ? "liked " : "haven't liked "
        return (<div>You {text} {this.state.name} 
            <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Like</button>
            <input value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </div>);
    }
}

class App extends React.Component<{}, AppState> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (<div>
            <Tester />
        </div>);
    }
}

function Factory(props: {}) {
  return React.createElement(App, props);
}

export = Factory;
```

The calling code is

```
/// <reference path="react/react-addons.d.ts" />
import React = require("react/addons");
import App = require("app");

React.render(App({}), document.getElementById("jsapp"));
```

The component renders as I would expect but `handleClick` and `handleChange` methods don't update the state correctly. If I put breakpoints in those two methods and `render` then I see the following values for `this`:

- `render`: `this` is a Tester object (what I would expect).
- `handleChange`: `this` is a `ReactClass.createClass.Constructor`.
- `handleClick`: `this` is a reference to the `Window` object.

The latter two mean that the state object isn't available.

Any suggestions gratefully received.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You must change your render method:

```
render() {
    // ...
        <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>Like</button>
        <input value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
    // ...
}
```

Since you're calling an event, the `this` keyword will be changed to the event's default context.
By using `.bind(this)` you ensure that the context being called will be the instance of your class.

Comment: Note that, while binding in render works, it does cause a performance problem. https://medium.com/@esamatti/react-js-pure-render-performance-anti-pattern-fb88c101332f#9bed

Comment: @CraigWalker great reading. In fact, I usually use the class properties with arrow functions to create my bound functions, but you're completely right talking about the example given in this answer! :)

Comment: You shouldn't bind in the `render` method, binding should be done in the constructor, binding in render creates a new function at each render.

Answer (score 16):

You have to bind methods with `this` because you don't use `React.createClass` that does it automatically.
Example with a class syntax:

```
class Counter extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange() {
    ...
  }
  handleClick() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Another method is to use fat arrow functions for event handlers which get automatic "this" binding.

```
 handleClick = (evt, domNode):void => {
     this.setState({ liked: !this.state.liked, name: this.state.name });
 };

 <button onClick={() => this.handleClick()}>Like</button>
```

Comment: Lambdas are forbidden in JSX attributes due to their rendering performance impact

Comment: Another post directly contradicts that they cause rendering issues. I've been curious about this as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43968779/are-lambda-in-jsx-attributes-an-anti-pattern/43968902#43968902

Comment: been debugging this issue for hours, you are my savior :)