# Are Lambda in JSX Attributes an anti-pattern?

Tags: reactjs

I started using a new linter today (tslint-react) and it is giving me the following warning:

"Lambdas are forbidden in JSX attributes due to their rendering performance impact"

I get that this causes the a new function to be created with each render. And that it could trigger unneeded re-renders because the child component will think it's props have changed.

But my question is this, how else can one pass parameters to an event handler inside a loop:

```
customers.map( c => <Btn onClick={ () => this.deleteCust(c.id) } /> );
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Definitely not an antipattern.

Lambdas (arrow functions) have no impact on rendering performance.

The only thing that has an impact is the implementation of `shouldComponentUpdate`. This function returns `true` by default, meaning that the component is always rendered. That means that even if the props don't change, the component is still rendered again. And that's the default behavior.

Changing arrow function to a bound method won't improve the performance if you don't implement `shouldComponentUpdate`.

It's true that not using arrow functions can simplify the implementation of `shouldComponentUpdate` and they should not be used with `PureComponent` but they are not an antipattern. They can simplify many patterns, e.g. when adding an additional parameter to function (e.g. what you are doing in your example).

Also note that React has stateless components which cannot even implement `shouldComponentUpdate` and therefore they are always rendered.

Don't think about performance impact until you actually find a performance problem.

Comment: There's a difference between render being called, and the actual DOM mutation. Because react reconciliation will not touch the DOM if the result of render is the same as before. But when using arrow functions the result of render will not be the same, so a DOM mutation will take place.

Comment: @Koen. I don't think that `onClick` handlers count when updating DOM. React does not bind the function directly to DOM because it has an abstraction layer (with synthesized events). Therefore changing the function should have no impact on DOM because DOM won't change.

Comment: Ah yeah, makes sense.

Answer (score 6):

Well as far as I know, it has an impact on performance even if you're not using `React.PureComponent` or `useMemo`. When you define anonymous arrow function (Lambda) in component's prop (JSX attribute), the same function is created on each render so that JS engine can't reuse it. **That recreation slows don't performance because JavaScript's engine garbage collector has to collect those unneccessary functions.**

There are several other approaches ***which behaves the same.*** Take a look at example below:

```
#1 Lamba approach
customers.map( c => <Btn onClick={ () => this.deleteCust(c.id) } /> );

#2 bind apprach
customers.map( c => <Btn onClick={ this.deleteCust.bind(this, c.id) } /> );

#3 call approach
customers.map( c => <Btn onClick={ this.deleteCust.call(this, c.id) } /> );

#4 apply approach
customers.map( c => <Btn onClick={ this.deleteCust.apply(this, [c.id]) } /> );
```

I would say the recommended approach is to create a separate function inside the component being mapped. Let's modify a bit your example:

```
const Btn = ({ clicked, customer }) => {
  const buttonClickHandler = () => {
    clicked(customer.id)
  }
  return <button onClick={buttonClickHandler}>Click me!</button> 
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <App>
      { customers.map(c => <Btn customer={c} clicked={deleteCust} />) }
    </App>
  )
}
```

So now, since instead of anonymous function (which can't be reused) we're using function expression in a constant, React doesn't recreate new function every new component re render and the garbage collector can rest in piece!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure on why they are / are not allowed, but regardless; Javascript allows us to declare functions within blocks of code like so

```
function mapCustomersToButton(c) {
  function handleBtnClick() {
    this.deleteCust(c.id);
  }

  return <Btn onClick={handleBtnClick} />
}

return customers.map(mapCustomersToButton);
```

The `handleBtnClick` function creates a closure around the `c` object being passed into it from the `mapCustomersToButton` function; preserving the reference.

This is equivalent to the following:

```
return customers.map(c => <Btn onClick={() => this.deleteCust(c.id)} />);
```